# Longitudinal CFA/SEM with autocorrelated/autoregressed indicators (in R, better with lavaan)

Tags: r, panel-data, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

**The problem is**, I am trying to fit a multilevel factor model to highly autocorrelated (in fact, autoregressive) indicators. More specifically, I have multiple measurements (60-70) per person (5-10 items) and want to find underlying factors for within- and between-person variations in the manifest variables. I am doing my analyses in R and would like to do them via lavaan if possible. For the simplicity, let's focus here on the first level, as if I assume I want to do it at individual level for only one person.

I can imagine how a cross-lagged model can capture changes in the latent variables, but I believe that, since the observations at different time points are highly correlated, the assumption of uncorrelated errors at different times does not hold. I am thinking of 'manually' (using a code to parse the model) writing the model with ~70 factor structures and then letting covariations between the same items at consecutive time points and constraining factor loadings to be the same across time.
That is, if I have one factor with two indicators $y_1$ and $y_2$, I allow correlation between $y_{1_{t_{i}}}$ and $y_{1_{t_{i+1}}}$ as well as between $y_{2_{t_{i}}}$ and $y_{2_{t_{i+1}}}$, and setting $\lambda_{1_{t_{i}}} = \lambda_{1_{t_{i+1}}}$ and $\lambda_{2_{t_{i}}} = \lambda_{2_{t_{i+1}}}$.

I couldn't find much theoretical CFA/SEM models on autocorrelated multiple measurements and I'm actually kind of lost here. **My first question is about the theoretical model**: Is what I described a correct understanding of/solution to the matter? Are there decent theoretical models tailored for this kind of problems?

**My second question is about coding it in R**; This approach of modeling that I just mentioned (having ~70 cross-lagged factor structures) seems too complicated and highly cumbersome to implement, debug, and evaluate. That would be worse if we consider that I might need to model the autoregression of indicators via a VAR model (vector $Y_{t_{i+1}} = [y_{1_{t_{i+1}}},y_{2_{t_{i+1}}}]$ is autoregressed on $Y_{t_{i}} = [y_{1_{t_{i}}},y_{2_{t_{i}}}]$), and that, eventually, another level will be stacked on top of all of these to explain between-person differences. Is there a nice(r) way of doing it in R, hopefully with lavaan?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That sounds like a heck of a model that you will struggle get to run. What's your sample size? I'd like to have thousands for a model of that complexity.

Comment: @JeremyMiles it defers from dataset to dataset. but mostly around 150-200. Maybe it's to few :(

Comment: If you try to do SEM with this many variables and that small a sample, your models will not be identified and will not run.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyMiles. I try to reduce the number of samples per person (maybe to 10 or 14?). However, what kind of model (and implementation) would you suggest for the problem?