# Markov property of manifest variables in longitudinal ESM

Tags: factor-analysis, markov-process, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable

I am working on a longitudinal ESM model were the indicators are (highly) autocorrelated. This means that the classic cross-lagged models of panel data analysis cannot be used directly. I have explained the main problem [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/400786/longitudinal-cfa-sem-with-autocorrelated-autoregressed-indicators-in-r-better) (although my proposed approach to model the sequence was very inefficient.) And I am going to discuss a one-level model (capturing the within-person variability of one individual) here to avoid further complications.

I have seen several papers and tutorials on dynamic structural equation models (DSEM) like [(Hamaker et al. 2018)](https://doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2018.1446819) and [(Asparouhovet al. 2018)](https://doi.org/10.1080/10705511.2017.1406803) and Mplus' learning material on DSEM ([here](https://www.statmodel.com/TimeSeries.shtml)). However, mostly in order to implement it in R (using lavaan) and to avoid limitations of their approaches, I decided to assume Markov property of lag one ($MP(1)$) which allows significant simplification (while there is suggestive evidence supporting it for the type of data I'm analyzing).

To illustrate my model, suppose that at each time point $t$, I have a vector of manifest variables $Y_{t_{n \times 1}} = [y^1_{t}, y^2_{t},..., y^n_{t}]^T$ and a vector of latent variables $\Theta_{t_{m \times 1}} = [\theta^1_{t}, \theta^2_{t}, ..., \theta^m_{t}]^T$, which are related by a loading matrix $\Lambda_{t_{n \times m}}$ such that $Y_t = \Lambda_t \Theta_t + \Delta_t$

Where $\Delta_{t_{n \times 1}} = [\delta^1_{t}, \delta^2_{t}, ..., \delta^n_{t}]^T$ is the vector of measurement errors of items.

I assume that my model has $MP(1)$ at the factor level, meaning that $P(\Theta_{t}|\Theta_{t-1}, \Theta_{t-2},..., \Theta_{1}) = P(\Theta_{t}|\Theta_{t-1})$. However, the manifest variables (at the item level) are (highly) autocorrelated, meaning that I cannot basically assume error independence, so in general $corr(\delta^i_{t}, \delta^j_{t}) \neq 0$. As a result, I have to take the autocorrelation of errors into account.

**My solution was** to make a new time series of consecutive observations $\Upsilon_{2n \times 1} = [Y_{t-1},Y_{t}]^T$, and as a result, I will have a new vector of factors $\Omega_{2m \times 1} = [\Theta_{t-1}, \Theta_{t}]^T$. I further assume measurement invariance accross time (i.e., $\Lambda_t = \Lambda$). Hence, I will have a new loading matrix $\Pi_{2n \times 2m} =
\begin{bmatrix} 
\Lambda & 0 \\
0 & \Lambda 
\end{bmatrix}$.

**However,** this formulation relies on the $MP(1)$ assumption, *both* at the factor level *and* at the item level. In other words, I have generalized the $MP(1)$ assumption from factor level to the item level, which might not be true.

**So, my question is,** am I *actually* allowed to assume $MP(1)$ at the item level given that $MP(1)$ is the case at the factor level?
How do I justify this choice and/or derive the independence of $Y_{t-2}$ and $Y_{t}$ implied by this assumption analytically?